# How do などという/なんて differ from とか/など?

Tags: nuances

I'm currently studying などという and なんて. I have seen that they ESSENTIALLY mean (things/people/etc. like~). However this confuses me with what's the difference between these and just とか?

As in a sentence like this: アメリカで空手なんてあまりできないから、日本にいるうちに経験してみたら？

My guess is that, if we look at などという and break it down, it's something (maybe) like, "the thing like/such as karate", it's adding some kind of emotion?? (as I have seen in some other research on this grammar). Or perhaps like, "you can't do anything even remotely similar to Karate in America! So why don't you experience it now?"

I can't work out if the above sentence is giving 空手 as an example or what. This is what is confusing me now between just regular など and とか.

I have looked at the other answers concerning  などという　and なんて but can't grasp it's meaning in some cases - as to whether it is truly giving an example or is working something like こんな/こういう like expressions etc.

EDIT: I guess the full sentence would be アメリカで空手などというスポーツあまりできないから.... so the sentence would literally mean "You can't do anything like karate in america" and is thus emphasis 空手 a bit?

Answer (score 2):

空手なんて - in this case, the speaker is giving karate some sort of special status, a specialty that you can only do in a particular situation (in this particular case, Japan) that the listener should take advantage

空手などということ - this is a bit similar to the above expression, except karate might be being listed among a number of other similar things. など (等) is the key word. Look at other structures where this is used. (E.g. AやBやC等...)

空手など - Using this expression in this context sounds rather flippant, so it sounds rather strange being used here. It does mean "such as," but it isn't treating karate as anything special, rather, as an item on a list of other similar things.

空手とか - "such as", but again, it isn't treating karate with any importance, which is why it would sound strange here.